# Tracking How Many Times a Button has been Clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timer

I have a popup which automatically loads when the page is loaded, it also has a timer on the close button whose time on it varies depending on how many times the popup was viewed by the user. It also has a 'Print' button and the popup can be called back up if you press the key 'g'.

My focus is on the 'Print' button. Currently when I click the 'Print' button it adds the following bit of code:

```
$("#timer").remove();
clearInterval(setMsg);
```

However if you were to reload the page the timer would reappear as if the button hadn't been clicked at all, it would be either `5`, `15`, `30`, `45` or `60` seconds depending on how many times you had previously viewed the page. I would like the timer to permanently be removed after the 'Print' button has been clicked.

Please note the timer does not appear to work in the snippet or the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChippeRock/wt1gb9of/4/) as I believe several of the functions are prevented from working such as `document.write`. However it will work in my browser when I create an HTML file. My code is below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.charCode === 65 || 103) {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
    }
  });
  
  $(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "visible");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 1);
  });

  $(".close").click(function() {
    $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
  });
});

// initialization
var counter = 60;
var timesVisited = 0;
var cookieExpirationDays = 7; // don't expire cookies for a week
// test to see if localstorage/sessionStorage is available (localStorage has no expiration date)

if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  counter = 60;
  timesVisited = localStorage.getItem("timesVisited");
  // first time
  if ((timesVisited == 0) || (timesVisited < 1)) {
    timesVisited = 1;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 60;
  }
  // second time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 1) && (timesVisited <= 3)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 45;
  }
  // third time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 4) && (timesVisited <= 8)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 30;
  }
  // fourth time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 9) && (timesVisited <= 13)) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 15;
  }
  // fifth time
  else if (timesVisited >= 14) {
    timesVisited++;
    localStorage.setItem("timesVisited", timesVisited);
    counter = 5;
  }
}
// No localstorage/sessionStorage. Use cookies 
else {
  timesVisited = getCookie("timesVisited");
  console.log(timesVisited);
  // first time
  if ((timesVisited == "") || (timesVisited < 1)) {
    timesVisited = 1;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 60;
  }
  // second time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 1) && (timesVisited <= 3)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 45;
  }
  // third time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 4) && (timesVisited <= 8)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 30;
  }
  // fourth time
  else if ((timesVisited >= 9) && (timesVisited <= 13)) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 15;
  }
  // fifth time
  else if (timesVisited >= 14) {
    timesVisited++;
    setCookie("timesVisited", timesVisited, cookieExpirationDays);
    counter = 5;
  }
}
var setMsg = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter >= 60 && counter >= 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 60 && counter < 70) {
    $("#close-message").html("1:0" + (counter - 60));
  } else if (counter >= 10) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:" + counter);
  } else if (counter > 0) {
    $("#close-message").html("0:0" + counter);
  } else {
    $(".close").click(function() {
      $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden");
      $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
    });
    $("#timer").remove();
    clearInterval(setMsg);
  }
}, 1000);
});

        function printDiv()
        {
            var content = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
            var win = window.open();
            win.document.write(content);
            win.print(); // JavaScript Print Function
            win.close(); //It will close window after Print.
        $( ".close" ).click(function() {
          $('#PopUp').css("visibility", "hidden"); 
          $('#PopUp').css("opacity", 0);
        });
        $("#timer").remove();
         clearInterval(setMsg);s
        }
```

```css
.t {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
  -moz-transform-origin: top left;
  -o-transform-origin: top left;
  -ms-transform-origin: top left;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.25);
  -o-transform: scale(0.25);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.25);
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: pre;
  overflow: visible;
}

#t1_1 {
  left: 256px;
  top: 35px;
  letter-spacing: 0.1px;
}

#t2_1 {
  left: 334px;
  top: 87px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t3_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 123px;
}

#t4_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 123px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#t5_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 141px;
}

#t6_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 160px;
}

#t7_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 179px;
}

#t8_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 141px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t9_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 160px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ta_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 179px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tb_1 {
  left: 343px;
  top: 242px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tc_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 278px;
}

#td_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 297px;
}

#te_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 315px;
}

#tf_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 334px;
}

#tg_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 278px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#th_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 297px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ti_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 315px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tj_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 334px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tk_1 {
  left: 286px;
  top: 393px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tl_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 429px;
}

#tm_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 448px;
}

#tn_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 466px;
}

#to_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 485px;
}

#tp_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 429px;
  word-spacing: -0.3px;
}

#tq_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 448px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tr_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 466px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#ts_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 485px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#tt_1 {
  left: 326px;
  top: 544px;
  letter-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#tu_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 580px;
}

#tv_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 599px;
}

#tw_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 618px;
}

#tx_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 618px;
}

#ty_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 636px;
}

#tz_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 636px;
}

#t10_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 655px;
}

#t11_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 580px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t12_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 599px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t13_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 655px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t14_1 {
  left: 264px;
  top: 716px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t15_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 752px;
}

#t16_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 771px;
}

#t17_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 789px;
}

#t18_1 {
  left: 210px;
  top: 808px;
}

#t19_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 752px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1a_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 771px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

#t1b_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 789px;
  word-spacing: -0.2px;
}

#t1c_1 {
  left: 238px;
  top: 808px;
  word-spacing: -0.1px;
}

.s1_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 85.4px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s2_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  FONT-WEIGHT: bold;
}

.s3_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: SymbolMT_1z5;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

.s4_1 {
  FONT-SIZE: 61.2px;
  FONT-FAMILY: Arial;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

div {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.button {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  background: orange;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  height: 578%;
  width: 117.5%;
}

.overlay:target {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: none;
}

.PopUp {
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 60%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.PopUp .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
}

.PopUp .close:hover {
  color: orange;
}

.PopUp .content {
  max-height: 117.5%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.pdf1 {
  width: 935px;
  height: 1210px;
  background-color: white;
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  z-index: 0;
  border: none;
}

button {
  background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #2D2D2D;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.Print {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.close-message {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: black;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  line-height: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 9px;
}

.timer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="PopUp" class="overlay">
  <div class="PopUp">
    <div class="timer" id="timer"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/87XaOWA.png">
      <p class="close-message" id="close-message"></p>
    </div>
    <a class="close" href="#">&#10005;</a>
    <div class="content" id="content">
      <div id="p1" class="p1" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; width: 885px; height: 878px;">
        <!-- Begin page background -->
        <div id="pg1Overlay" style="width:100%; height:100%; position:absolute; z-index:1; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0); -webkit-user-select: none;"></div>
        <div id="pg1" class="pg1" style="-webkit-user-select: none;"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/vcY42CW.png" id="pdf1" class="pdf1"></img>
        </div>
        <!-- End page background -->

        <!-- Begin text definitions (Positioned/styled in CSS) -->
        <div id="t1_1" class="t s1_1">Player Selection Criteria Evaluator Cue Card</div>
        <div id="t2_1" class="t s2_1">Skating – speed, quickness, technique</div>
        <div id="t3_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t4_1" class="t s4_1">Forward and Backward</div>
        <div id="t5_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t6_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t7_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t8_1" class="t s4_1">Turn both directions</div>
        <div id="t9_1" class="t s4_1">Stop both directions</div>
        <div id="ta_1" class="t s4_1">Are they in a good position for stability and strength</div>
        <div id="tb_1" class="t s2_1">Passing – technique, control, vision</div>
        <div id="tc_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="td_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="te_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tf_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tg_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and Backhand</div>
        <div id="th_1" class="t s4_1">To moving and stationary target</div>
        <div id="ti_1" class="t s4_1">Vision – do they take a look and select best option</div>
        <div id="tj_1" class="t s4_1">Advanced – board passes, chips, saucer passes</div>
        <div id="tk_1" class="t s2_1">Puck Control – technique, open ice, confined space</div>
        <div id="tl_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tm_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tn_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="to_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tp_1" class="t s4_1">Open carry with speed</div>
        <div id="tq_1" class="t s4_1">Execute dekes and fakes on the 1 on 1</div>
        <div id="tr_1" class="t s4_1">Can they handle the puck in traffic and tight space</div>
        <div id="ts_1" class="t s4_1">Ability to maintain control while being stick checked</div>
        <div id="tt_1" class="t s2_1">Shooting – technique, accuracy, velocity</div>
        <div id="tu_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tv_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tw_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tx_1" class="t s4_1">Velocity</div>
        <div id="ty_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="tz_1" class="t s4_1">Accuracy</div>
        <div id="t10_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t11_1" class="t s4_1">Forehand and backhand</div>
        <div id="t12_1" class="t s4_1">Wrist shot, snap shot, slap shot</div>
        <div id="t13_1" class="t s4_1">Shot Selection – do they select the best shot for the opportunity?</div>
        <div id="t14_1" class="t s2_1">Game Understanding – Principles of Offence and Defence</div>
        <div id="t15_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t16_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t17_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t18_1" class="t s3_1">♦</div>
        <div id="t19_1" class="t s4_1">Player understands positional play</div>
        <div id="t1a_1" class="t s4_1">Player supports the puck on the defensive and offensive side of puck</div>
        <div id="t1b_1" class="t s4_1">Player communicates with teammates</div>
        <div id="t1c_1" class="t s4_1">Player has the ability to read and react.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="Print" class="Print" align="center">
      <button onclick="printDiv()"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/HcXNoMC.png" /></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a popup which automatically loads when the page is loaded,

I very much dislike this but back to the point. What you want to do is store "somewhere" that the button has been clicked, since clicking this button only has an effect on the front end user, and I believe storing it on the server side is not useful, I would keep it in the web browser.

There are a couple of options to store temporary information in the browser, cookies for example but [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) is simple and modern, this bit of code would check if a variable has been set or not:

```
if (localStorage.getItem("btn_clicked") !== null) {
    // Show the pop-up
}
```